# No-boot/black screen with 4Gb DDR3 SoDimm upgrade and Dualcore Intel N570 Atom and motherboard HP (3594) v34.11

Tags: memory

I would really value some help - and not too complex! (I have big holes in my knowledge...)

I am trying to upgrade RAM (SoDimm) from 2Gb to 4Gb in an HP Mini 210 Netbook 3000 series (model is 3024sf) . Problem: black screen/will not boot.

Chip is Intel Atom N570, dual-core, 1.66Ghz. 
(More details below.)

I understood from net search that the N570 chip *SHOULD* run 4Gb... according to various reports and authors - but there are conflicting voices on this. I have searched this site, and looked at similar questions but not yet found a definitive answer.

Intel site itself says 2Gb max ... which does seem to be 'definitive'.

BUT:
One example found so far of N570 with 4Gb - is the massive, and low-power-consumption SeaMicro Server SM10000-64 with 256 N570 chipsets, where 'each Atom CPU can be configured with 2Gb or 4Gb...'

```
- datasheet spec here:  http://www.seamicro.com/sites/default/files/SM10000-64_DataSheet_v1%202.pdf
- infosheet here: http://www.seamicro.com/sites/default/files/SM_TO02_64_v1.7.pdf)
```

I have tried both Transcend and Kingston.   These are both 1600 (the HP takes 1333), but I understand faster RAM should run slower at the speed the computer can manage - ie it is backward-compatible.
It is on Windows 7 32, but the chip is described as '64' and dual core-dual processor -- another reason to imagine it COULD /SHOULD access the 4Gb and not give a black screen...

So - does anyone know of a way past this apparent '2Gb block'?
(Please, this is NOT a question about '4Gb limits in Winx32' - only about my wife's netbook not even booting with a 4Gb stick.  Once it boots - it opens other possibilities.
According to the AIDA64 report, PAE is already enabled.)

```
Chip is Intel Atom N570, dual-core, 1.66Ghz.

CPUID gives this info:
Chipset  
Northbridge Intel Atom Host Bridge rev. 02
Southbridge Intel NM10 rev. 02
Memory Type DDR3

Tests with AIDA64 'Extreme Edition' and info below is from it.
Memory Slots: (current stick) -- 
DRAM Slot #1    2 GB (DDR3-1333 DDR3 SDRAM)  (sodimm)

North Bridge Properties:
North Bridge            Intel Pineview-M IMC
Intel Platform          Pine Trail-M
Supported Memory Types  DDR2-667 SDRAM   (*see below)
Maximum Memory Amount   4 GB*
Revision                02
```

*I note the report shows "DDR2-667 SDRAM" - yet there is DDR3 in it and it runs normally...

I can post more of the report from CPUID or Aida64 Extreme Edition, if needed.

Any help very gratefully received!
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your HP mini does only only support up to 2 GByte Ram. 4 GByte will not work.

[See this HP Specifiation of the HP Mini 210 3024SF](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&objectID=c03018944&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=5082191).

Also the [Intel Specification of the Atom N570](http://ark.intel.com/products/55637/Intel-Atom-Processor-N570-1M-Cache-1_66-GHz) lists a maximum of 2 GByte RAM.

*(There may be some "unlocked" Netbooks with the same processor but maybe other chipset that would enable 4GByte to work - but still not sure if then really have the whole Memory available)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
That is clearly the 'official' view from those sites - yet it is also 'official view' that Win32 cannot use the whole of 4Gb -- yet there are people using it, and higher (PAE enabled, at least).

Since posting I have seen one user with a slightly different problem, who found the difference was made between using ram sticks with 1x8 bank of chips (4 a side) or 2 banks of 8 (8 chips a side) -- that ram with 4 chips a side would work, but 8 a side would not.

Comment: I hope to find similar ram in a shop and try it... - nothing to lose.
Would v. like to know if a hardware block/impossible, or a software limitation, as with Win32/4Gb.

Anybody tried?

Comment: Regarding comment "...but still not sure if then really have the whole Memory available" - I have done a lot of reading on that on the net, but cannot yet give personal experience. However the knowledgeable posts from USERS show they are indeed USING the whole of the ram - as shown both by test-software reports, and by loading under stress/making full use of/ ram, to ensure it is not a trick of words, but a reality of results.  (The subjective results are also most convincing.)
Hence trying hard to get a result here - it is so dissappointing if there is an impenetrable 2Gb hardware ceiling.

Comment: Yes maybe try one with 8 bank of chips - but I'm not sure if its anymore worth to invest too much into something you don't even know if it's working. Maybe try to improve the Memory consumption in Windows with some tools (like Soluto). Not loading unnecessary services at Windows Start and so on - you will get hundreds of MByte back.

Answer (score 0):

Is your OS WINDOWS 7 STARTER?? Then that might be the problem most probably. WINDOWS 7 STARTER comes only in 32-bit versions and never in 64-bit versions. All 32-bit Operating Systems will take only a maximum of 3GB of RAM, but, MS WINDOWS 7 STARTER will not boot if the RAM installes is more than 2GB. Try it with any 64-bit OS, and, hopefully, you'll have no issues there. It'll work fine with Widows XP 32-bit, but, mind you, it (XP 32-bit) will still take only 3GB of RAM atmost and the rest will sit there simply idle-not at all going to be used up. But XP 64-bit will definitely boot up and run without any isuues. This is from my personal experiences over the past 2 years.

Comment: Where did you find information that Windows 7 Starter edition will not boot if ram exceeds 2GB?

Comment: http://feilipu.me/2011/05/18/windows-7-starter-with-up-to-128gb-ram/

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 Starter comes only in 32-bit edition and so far, never in 64-bit edition. I've performed the task of adding more RAM (8GB or even 4GB Single Module) into a netbook running on Windows 7 Starter and all of them have never booted into the OS, but returned with a BSOD(Blue Screen Of Death) message everytime. This is from my personal Experience.